# Can I make a discord.py bot run a app on my computer?

Tags: python, discord

I have a Minecraft smp and I want it to start up when one of my member run a slash command on discord is that possible?

I tried this in JavaScript it didn't work so I went to python and tried a couple of things still did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide some examples of Python code that you've tried.

Comment: Jumping between languages every time you get a syntax error is not a productive way to write code.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: **yes**.

Consider starting by looking at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module for invoking shell commands.